# The choice of the tense in this sentence

Tags: tense

Let's say I've been trying to fix some glitches of someone's computer for one hour. Which of the following is better or if both are correct what is the difference?

> I give up! Nothing I try works.
>
> I give up! Nothing I try is working.

Comment: Both are possible and there is no significant difference in meaning. You might also say "Nothing I have tried has worked."